# What does "Enable OEM Unlock" do, and how can I do it through a root shell?

Tags: adb, fastboot, shell, bootloader-lock, nexus-6p

Looking at [this Samsung Galaxy A8 question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148099/enable-oem-unlock-via-build-prop-edit), I was looking to do something on my Nexus 6p.  I would like to enable OEM unlocking, the developer setting.  Due to the problems my device is experiencing, I would like to do this through the android root shell.  What does "Enable OEM Unlock" do on the device, and how can I replicate that change using a terminal.  It's on pure nexus, if that helps.

For anyone who wants to know, this is the current state of my device, if there are other possibility:

My recovery partition appears to be corrupted enough to be unusable, my main os (pure nexus) appears to be fine, but considers my phone to be corrupt and tries to reboot into recovery after I give it a password to decrypt my device (which I never set, and any password it calls correct and corrupted data).  So, I have root access in adb, including shell access which as far as it looks from me is the full device.  Using adb, I have tried opening the settings menu, which tells me that the current user(none) cannot change the "enable OEM unlocking" status.  But, that setting must be doing something simple to allow the device to be unlocked, right?

So, this is probably my fault, and will NEVER be done again, but I got to this state from trying to lock the boot loader after I got most of pure nexus working, as I just wanted to wipe it from any excess, figured I could kill 2 birds with one stone.  Since then, I have tried every factory reset I could find out there, all either need a working recovery(for the side loading a google signed recovery) or need an unlocked bootloader.

Comment: I believe you can flash a stock ROM without unlocking bootloader, and it will reset the recovery partition as well. Use Odin.